# How to combine two columns of dataframe with Nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to get the result column as follows while combining column1 and column2?

| index | c1 | c2 | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | b | c | b c |
| 3 | NaN | d | NaN |
| 4 | NaN | NaN | NaN |

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['res'] = df['c1'].str.cat(df['c2'], sep=' ')
print (df)
        c1   c2 result  res
index                      
1        a  NaN    NaN  NaN
2        b    c    b c  b c
3      NaN    d    NaN  NaN
4      NaN  NaN    NaN  NaN
```